# Generating a select tag with rails with range of numbers with steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

What is the simplest way to write a rails select tag that will generate a select for the numbers 1-15 stepped in .5 increments?

I know this has to be simple but i'm struggling with the syntax, i know there has to be a more elegant way to write it than how i did.

thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
select_tag "sizes", options_for_select((4..15).step(0.5))
```

This is how i wrote it... but is this the best way to approach?

also, if i wanted the 4.0/5.0/6.0 etc to read 4/5/6 as whole numbers, is there a way to do/include this on one line?

Comment: You can map the values and convert them from floats to fixnums if they are whole numbers: `(4..15).step(0.5).map{ |n| n % 1 == 0 ? n.to_i : n }`

Answer (score 3):

```
select_tag "sizes", options_for_select( (4..15).step(0.5).map{|n| n%1 == 0 ? n.to_i : n} )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `options_for_select` method does what you want, but only if you can seed it with the correct data. This means you need an array with the appropriate values in it. For example:

```
options_for_select((0..28).to_a.collect { |v| v.to_f / 2 + 1 })
```